# laravel pagination and sort table

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, pagination

I'm using sort function and pagination but the problem when I use sort for any column works fine but when I click to the next page using pagination the sort change and have to click on the column again for sorting.
so how to keep sorting while using pagination?

```html
<tr>
    <th>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-replace">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk-3">

        </div>
    </th>

    <th>@sortablelink('details','Details')</th>
    <th>@sortablelink('postingdate','Date')</th>
    <th>@sortablelink('description','Description')</th>
    <th>@sortablelink('amount','Amount')</th>
    <th>@sortablelink('type','Type')</th>
    <th>@sortablelink('slip','Slip#')</th>
    <th>@sortablelink('vendor_id','Vendor')</th>
    <th>@sortablelink('category_id','Category')</th>
</tr>
```

```php
public function index()
{
    $checks = Checks::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

    $checks= Checks::sortable()->paginate(5);

    return view('home',compact('checks'));
}
```

Comment: First of all you should add some information about package which you are using in your code (If I am not mistaken that is **Kyslik/column-sortable**). Besides, delete first string from index method `$checks = Checks::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();` because after it You assign `$checks` value new data (this is not right) and add more information for your view (for example pagination code).

Comment: I include [full example in the docs](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable#full-example), so yea as answer suggest you need to leverage `appends()` on the paginated model instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can append query string to your link by doing this :

```
{{ $users->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->links() }}
```

replace `sort` by your sortable query, and `votes` by something like `request()->sort`

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/pagination-and-column-sorting), you also can do your pagination like this:

```
//Controller
public function index()
{
    $checks = Checks::orderBy('id')->paginate(5);
    $links = $checks ->appends(['sort' => 'id'])->links();

    return view('home', compact('checks', 'links'));
}
```

And in your view, you can just call your pagination links like this

```
{{ $links }}
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`{{links()}}` will still give a messed up sort when you paginate. This is the same as `{!! link() !!}` also and `{{ $checks->links()}}`
Rather, use the code below. It will correct the error.

```
//for the Controller
public function index()
{
    $checks = Checks::sortable()->paginate(5);

    return view('home', compact('checks'));
}
//for the blade template in laravel append this in  div after the table

{!! $checks->appends(\Request::except('page'))->render() !!}][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this line in your blade file

```
{!! $product->appends(\Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).